# White flickering when changing pages using an Image Background in React-native

Tags: react-native

**The Problem**

I have a Stack Navigator. When I switch from Page A to Page B (who uses the same `ImageBackground` component the next screen appears instantly but without the background Image. Only after about 1 - 2 seconds is it appearing. I use a background image (just a complex gradient which you can't do with `react-native`, so I exported it as image) for every page on my app. So I created a component called `Container` that just exports an `ImageBackground` with the passed in Background image. It looks like this:

```
const BackgroundImageContainer = styled.ImageBackground`
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1;
`;

const Container = ({children}) => (
  <BackgroundImageContainer
    source={require('../assets/Background.png')}
    style={{flex: 1, width: null, height: null}}>
    {children}
  </BackgroundImageContainer>
);
```

I also have a tab bar and when I switch to different tabs the screen "flashes white" because I see the white background for a sec and then it shows the actual Background Image.

**I think it has something to do with loading time of the image (although it's just 160KB).
How do I load this image when the app starts and then "caches" it so it's available to all components "instantly" ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues/160#issuecomment-373938649), it should help you sort out image caching.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Or maybe it's just a problem with the dev server, since image is served over http? I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34272286/how-to-prevent-static-images-in-react-native-from-stuttering-loading-asynchron

Comment: I just made a build and deployed to my iPhone and over there everything is butter smooth :D

Comment: glad it worked smoothly for you :), also please mark the answer so others don't run into the same issue :D

Comment: @GeraltDieSocke this answer worked for you?

if this is the case, make it an accepted answer haha
i'm trying to search an way to fix the same issue as you. but i dont know how you made it work

Comment: (Because in my case it receives the image over an api, so i think i'm going to suffer the same issue even with a released version)

Comment: @WiliamBrochensquejunior I can't remember but according to my comment it worked very good :D Sorry I forgot to acceppt it. Done it now + upvote